# EntityManager does not have getCriteriaBuilder( )?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, netbeans, glassfish

JPAController method complains like the following:

[image]

I am using Netbeans 7.3.1 on OS X Lion, Glassfish 4, Java EE 7.

Comment: Have you manually added some JPA / javax.persistence libraries to your project?

Comment: JPA is added automatically when Glassfish is added as the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Possibility 1:** You have a *wrong library* on your path. Try to click on the EntityManager class to see where it leads and remove that part from your build path, so that GlassFish's libraries are taken.

**Possibility 2:** Also it could be your *Glassfish version* referenced in your project (an older version with JPA 1.0, version that does not have CriteriaQueries).

Comment: JPA 2.1 is on the classpath.

Comment: You can have multiple versions of JPA on your classpath. Did you find out, which library is taken, by clicking/navigating in the EntityManager class in code (use the corresponding CTRL key and right-mouse click)? Also did you try a "Clean Project" ?

Comment: When I navigate to the EntityManager source, no getCriteriaBuilder() available there! I don't know where this old JAR come from and why the new JARs are ignored! Thanks for pointing the root of the issue.

Comment: Problem is solved by removing the JAP 1.0 JAR which was in the classpath.